# How to check same class having same attribute with unique value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few same class elements having same attribute with unique value, like

```
<div class="myclass" data="1"></div>
<div class="myclass" data="2"></div>
<div class="myclass" data="3"></div>
<div class="myclass" data="4"></div>
```

Is there a way to check condional like

```
if($('.myclass').hasAttr('data').hasVal('2'))
// want to do something
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is. It's called `$.fn.is`

```
if($('.myclass').is('[data=2]'))
  // do something
```

I would suggest against the use of custom attributes that do not adhere to the spec. So, just use data-api attributes.
Something like below

```
<div class="myclass" data-num="1"></div>
<div class="myclass" data-num="2"></div>
```

and  `if($('myclass').is('[data-num=2]')){}`

Comment: +One for nice explanation

Comment: what if i need value of another attribute of same element?

Comment: @deveshchauhan27 just do `is("[attributename='attributevalue']")`

Comment: @deveshchauhan27 it would be `$('.myclass').is('[data-val=abc]')`

Comment: @deveshchauhan27 if it helped, please do mark it as answer by clicking the tick mark.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the element by data value using jquery and then use the returned length as condition in if statement:

```
if($('.myclass[data=2]').length)
    //do something
```

**### Demo**